# HTML equal border width and forcing line break

Tags: html, formatting, border

I have a HTML part that looks like this:

[image: Table]

Is it possible to have an equal border with for every word? And how can I achieve a line break after "Köln"? I tried `<br/>`, but it doesn't work. Something that looks like this:

[image: soll]

Here is the HTML codepart:

```js
function openLink(url) {
  window.open(url);
}
```

```css
#sideNavBox {
  display: none
}

#contentBox {
  margin-left: 0px
}

.dd13:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dd13 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  Font: 12px Arial background-color:: #48A040;
  Padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<font size="3"><b>Seminare nach Standort filtern</b></font>
<div>
  <font size="3"><b><br/></b></font>
  <div>
    <br/>
    <table class="dd13">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Ulm&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Ulm</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Taufkirchen&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Taufkirchen</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Oberkochen&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Oberkochen</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Köln&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Köln</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Friedrichshafen&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Friedrichshafen</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Wetzlar&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Wetzlar</td>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">&#160;</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(&#39;/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Kiel&#39;);" class="dd13" style="color: black; border: 3px solid limegreen; font-size: 17px;">Kiel</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <p>
      <br/>
    </p>
    <p>To register yourself to a seminar please click on this icon
      <a title="Book for me" class="book-for-me-button"></a>. To register someone else to a seminar, please click on this icon
      <a title="Book for me" class="book-for-user-button"></a>.<br/></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use table if you do not want a table. Use DIVs with display:flex

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data - this looks more like a list of links so probably would be more semantically correct using a `ul` or `div`.  Also the `font` tag is obsolete and should not be used - use css instead, and you probably want to use the `strong` tag instead of the `b` tag (or maybe a heading tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at flex

Note the click below does not open a page because the stacksnippet sandbox is blocking new windows

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("link")) {
      window.open(tgt.getAttribute("data-link"));
      [...document.querySelectorAll(".link.active")].forEach(lnk => lnk.classList.remove("active"));
      tgt.classList.add("active");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 0px
}

.link {
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid lime;
  border-radius: 15px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: lime
}
```

```html
<h3><b>Seminare nach Standort filtern</b></h3>
<div id="nav">
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Ulm">Ulm</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Taufkirchen">Taufkirchen</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Oberkochen">Oberkochen</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Köln">Köln</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Friedrichshafen">Friedrichshafen</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Wetzlar">Wetzlar</div>
  <div class="link" data-link="/internalseminars/SitePages/InternalSeminars.aspx?locations=Kiel">Kiel</div>
</div>
<div id="register">
  <p>To register yourself to a seminar please click on this icon
    <a title="Book for me" class="book-for-me-button"></a>. To register someone else to a seminar, please click on this icon
    <a title="Book for me" class="book-for-user-button"></a>.<br/></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this I can't click on the links anymore. Do you know why?

Comment: @PoliticsStudent Please replace your openLink function with all the script I wrote

Comment: @PoliticsStudent I forgot the rounded corners ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding them. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to forget the "table" element for these cards, then try it with "span" and flexbox. you can set fixed width to it easily and it automatically breaks the line itself.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="card">example 1</span>
  <span class="card">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
  <span class="card">example</span>
  <span class="card">test</span>
  <span class="card">paragraph</span>
  <span class="card">Day</span>
  <span class="card">Night</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Much easier to see if your code works that way

Answer (score 1):

When you are using table, every row should be in a `<tr>`. So for line break it's better to add a new `<tr>`. and if you want to have same width for your cells, you can set width for `<td>`. For example:

```
<style>
      table {
      table-layout: fixed ;
      width: 100% ;
    }
    td {
        width: 25% ;
       text-align: center;
       color: black;
       border: 3px solid limegreen;
       font-size: 17px
    }
 </style>
```

and your table:

```
   <table class="dd13">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Ulm</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Taufkirchen</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Oberkochen</td>
          <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Köln</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Friedrichshafen</td>
            <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Wetzlar</td>
            <td onclick="openLink(#);" class="dd13">Kiel</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```